# Using a DMM to measure output isolation/crosstalk

Tags: measurement, multimeter

I'm making some PCB's that have some DC to DC converters on them with three 5 Volt converters, one 15 volt converter, and a converter with +/- 12 volts DC.

[image: DC-to-DC converter]

On the PCB the output pins are in a connector that are fairly close to each other. I want to make sure that there is isolation between all the supply outputs. The +/-12 supply shares the same common between them, but I"ll have to check to make sure that common isn't shorted to the +15volts for example.

I need to be able to test about 20 of these boards.

My idea is I'm already doing line/load regulation on these supplies so I have the DMM in VDC mode. After the line/load regulation test, I leave the positive lead of the DMM on the first supply, then I move the negative lead to each supply. I should measure the supply voltage output of the first supply, then zero VDC moving the negative lead to each supply.

Then I move on to the next supply leave the positive on that supply, and test all the negative pins making sure they are 0 VDC.

My question is, should I also do this for the positive pins for each supply?

Example: Now leave the Negative lead on the supply, and move the Positive lead to each supply making sure it is also 0VDC, or would this step be redundant?

Comment: Why does isolation/crosstalk matter in this case? They are all separate supplies with separate circuits. Even if you were to test them, it really only matters in the PCB layout whether they get too close. A DMM would not be sufficient for this testing because really for crosstalk you need to sweep a range of frequencies and see how many dB. Still, this is done in signal lines, not usually power supplies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Info about DC/DC converters

DC to DC converters are usually isolating types with a rating of 1500VAC input to output. The rating comes from UL60950 and 1500VAC is twice incoming voltage plus 1000VAC. A lot of manufacturers of dc converters choose to meet this spec because, if the converter is an isolating type it's an easy design aim to achieve.

## Back to your question

To want to test the isolation capabilites of the circuit board means there is some requirement for your company to do so and this may be because the power supplies are intended for medical or other sensitive applications.

You must therefore ask yourself what is the motivation for this test.

If the circuit board is designed correctly and parts bought from reputable sources then there should be no need to test isolation except whenever either this isolation is relied upon from a safety standpoint or the power supply outputs MUST be isolated to each other for correct funtionality.

If after all of this you decide it is a safety consideration, then you should do the proper test at 1500VAC (250VAC supplies) or equivalent peak converted to DC i.e. 2121Vdc.

If you decide it is a functional requirement rather than a safety requirement then using a DMM will barely indicate anything - try switching the incoming supply off and measuring resistance between one output and another - this will probably tell you more but still it is likely to be insufficient for just a functional requirement test.

Comment: Its for functional testing. The boards are being manufactured and we just need to see if there are any solder bridges/etc. It would save time to leave the meters in voltage mode and just make sure there is 0VDC from the positive of the current supply, while moving the negative to the other supply outputs to make sure no negatives are shorted with the current supply. Then do the same thing for positive.

Comment: @zacharoni16 I think you'd do better with a little test harness that connected all the outputs in series temporarily; 15V gnd to 12V+, 15V+ to 5V gnd, 5V+ to next 5V gnd. You'd be able to measure -12V, +12V, +27V, +32V, +37V and +42V. The test fixture could connect onto the output connector

Comment: The problem with that is if you put them in series in the test fixture, it will miss if say the GND of the first +5V converter is shorted to the +5V output of the second +5V converter. Since that "failure" will put the two in series like the test fixture already does.

Comment: @zacharoni16 point well made - maybe have a test fixture that connects in scenario A then swap it out to scenario B where the opposite connections are made.

Comment: So in summary you would like to not waste time switching to resistance mode on your DMM ? to check for solder bridges. This is hardly a huge time waster. And are the circuits designed such that there is a real risk of this happening?

Comment: @Spoon The tests are actually automated through relays/Labview, I dont want to switch the meter from VDC to resistance for every board. To save on wear/tear on the equipment.

basically All the input lines are connected to the DMM via normally open contacts of relays. And then labview controls the relays and reads the voltage reading for each line

Comment: For 20 boards that's not many times... unless that's 20 boards at a time and your making 100's of boards a month then you have a point. I've used Labview and various relays for switching the DMM. Most of the time the relays last a lot longer than the datasheets say.